# How can I configure the layers of the neruonal network to generate a 400x400 image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

Hello I am starting in the world of neural networks, I have taken as a total basis the example of the book "Python Deep Learning" from the publisher Marcombo, in this a Generative Adversarial Networks is generated based on an example of the book, the following was developed code

```
# Esta es la linea original 
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
# se reemplazo por la siguiente linea
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 400, 400, 1).astype('float32')

train_images = (train_images - 127.5) / 127.5 # esta linea normaliza de -1 a 1 los datos 

BUFFER_SIZE = 60000
BATCH_SIZE = 256
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_images).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Reshape, Conv2DTranspose, BatchNormalization, LeakyReLU

def make_generator_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(7*7*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))

    model.add(Reshape((7, 7, 256)))

    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))

    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))

    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='tanh'))

    return model
generator = make_generator_model()
generator.summary ()

noise_dim = 100
noise = tf.random.normal([1, noise_dim])
generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)

plt.imshow(generated_image[0, :, :, 0], cmap='gray')
```

This generates a noise image that will be trained until it looks like the training image, "train_images", the original data of the example is from a 28x28 image, my intention is to use data from an image that is 400x400 that has already been loaded successfully but when it tries to load the image it tells me that it is not possible.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-73ddb44f2cff> in <module>()
    182 if __name__ == "__main__":
    183     execute = Read()
--> 184     execute.read()

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py in random_uniform(self, shape, minval, maxval, dtype)
   1831     return tf.random.uniform(
   1832         shape=shape, minval=minval, maxval=maxval, dtype=dtype,
-> 1833         seed=self.make_legacy_seed())
   1834 
   1835   def truncated_normal(self, shape, mean=0., stddev=1., dtype=None):

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[100,2560000] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:RandomUniform]
```

My specific intention is to generate a noise image of size 400x400 so that it can be trained with an image that measures 400x400

How can I configure the layers of the neruonal network to generate a 400x400 image?

All the cited code was taken from the book "Python Deep Learning" by Jordi Torres.

Comment: Your system can't load such large images. Try using a system which has more memory.

Comment: I'd say you can first reduce the batch size. To try if this is the problem here, try setting the batch size to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your error messege "OOM" is mentioned wich means out of memory. This messege occurs when you try to allocate more data on your GPU as is available. You have the following options:

1. decrease the batch size
2. reduce the spatial dimensions of your data
3. Use GPU with more memory.